# Problem with header/footer on first page when content is inserted before TOC

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I'm trying to insert a first page without header/footer. It works when I insert a TOC right after the first page, but not when I do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Preamble}

\begin{document}

% \mytitle{Title}{SubTitle}{SubSubTitle}
\mytitle{name}{group-number}{version}

\include{Introduction.tex}
```

The version which works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Preamble}

\begin{document}

% \mytitle{Title}{SubTitle}{SubSubTitle}
\mytitle{name}{group-number}{version}

\tableofcontents
\include{Introduction.tex}
```

using this command defined in the Preamble.sty

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\mytitle[3]{
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\begingroup
\newlength\drop
\setlength\drop{0.08\textheight}
\centering
% \vspace*{\drop}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm} \\ \vspace*{20pt}
{\huge\bfseries subTitle - #1 %Titel
}\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape \Large #2}  %Undertitel
\\[\baselineskip]
{\scshape  #3}  %Undertitel
\\ \vspace*{10pt}{\scshape 
}
\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}
\\[\baselineskip]
\vspace*{0.4\drop}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{logo.png}
\end{figure}{}
% \vfill
\vspace*{0.4\drop}

{\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l r}
        Name                                        & Study number \\\hline
        person                     & studyNumber \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}}\par
\vfill
{\scshape university \\ \today %Dato og sted
\\
}\par 
\setcounter{page}{0}
\endgroup}
\makeatother
```

And I have tried using `\newpage` and `\clearpage`.
Please help me find a solution in where I can have the front page with no page format (header/footer/page number) and still have content before the TOC

Comment: Don't use the `table` or `figure` environments in `\mytitle`, these create floats (content that can be placed in a flexible manner) and in your example, you don't want those things to be floating in any way (as it's written `[H]` is essentially just undoing the `figure` and `tabular` environments).  Just the `tabular` environment and `\includegraphics` macro will do.

Comment: Thank you @DaiBowen. It makes sense, but I didn't think of floats in that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I added `\thispagestyle{empty}` at the beginning of the `\mytitle` command